# Cannot start but can enable and start service

Tags: systemd, services

I created service for strelaysvr:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing Relay Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/strelaysrv -keys /srv/strelaysrv/keys
User=strelaysrv

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and placed it into */srv/strelaysvr/strelaysvr.service*, which I symlinked into */etc/systemd/system*.

Then went on and `systemctl enable`d it , `systemctl start`ed it, and all works, fine, until reboot: after that, it seems to "disappear":

```
root@here:~# systemctl start strelaysrv
Failed to start strelaysrv.service: Unit strelaysrv.service not found.
root@here:~# ll /etc/systemd/system/strelaysrv.service 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Apr  2 22:59 /etc/systemd/system/strelaysrv.service -> /srv/strelaysrv/strelaysrv.service
root@here:~# ll /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/strelaysrv.service 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Apr  2 23:00 /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/strelaysrv.service -> /srv/strelaysrv/strelaysrv.service
root@here:~# ll /srv/strelaysrv/strelaysrv.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 185 Apr  2 22:58 /srv/strelaysrv/strelaysrv.service
```

But just calling `systemctl enable` succeeds and I can start it again!  What am I doing wrong?  Am I hitting a systemd bug?

```
root@here:~# lsb_release -a |& grep escr
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
root@here:~# dpkg -s systemd | grep ersion
Version: 232-25+deb9u3
```

Comment: should not there be `After=multi-user.target`

Comment: @GAD3R Why? That does not seem like a safe thing to do. Also as I said, I can start the service after I call `systemctl enable`, so the ownership is right.

Comment: Is `/srv` mounted when systemd tries to load the .service file at boot?

Comment: @MarkStosberg Good quesion.  /srv is actually a symlink to under /home, which is mounted as `UUID=redacted /home ext4 defaults 0 0` in fstab.  (My apache vhosts do rely on /srv, nothing except strelaysrv has unit file there, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit file (in this case `strelaysrv.service` needs to be in a partition that is already mounted when systemd starts, which is not the case in your example, since in the comments you mentioned `/srv` is a symlink to under `/home` which is in its own partition.

This comes up fairly often in systemd bug reports, for a recent one see [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8307).

See also the (recently updated) [man page for systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) which states:

> The file system where the linked unit files are located must be accessible when systemd is started (e.g. anything underneath /home or /var is not allowed, unless those directories are located on the root file system).

The recommended solution is for you to create a copy of `strelaysrv.service` under `/etc/systemd/system` rather than a symlink. That should fix the issue.